# ComboBox trying to set selected item results in Compile error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to select an item in a ComboBox in a UserForm. I found the .Selected(index)=True code almost everywhere but for me it sais:

```
Compile error: Method or data member not found.
```

My code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim worksheetList As New ArrayList
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    worksheetList.Add ws.Name
Next ws

sourceWorksheets.List = worksheetList.toArray
destinationWorksheets.List = worksheetList.toArray

sourceWorksheets.Selected(1) = True 'Error here

End Sub
```

Am I doing something wrong? I couldn't really find any other function which would set the "default" item.

Comment: Arraylist and .toarray look to be vb.net code, not excel vba

Comment: `sourceWorksheets.Listindex = 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Rory keeps saying - use `ListIndex` to select an item in the list control.

This piece of code will add each sheet name to the list control and then select the first item:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Me.worksheetList.AddItem ws.Name
    Next ws

    Me.worksheetList.ListIndex = 0

End Sub
```

I think the OP was trying to use the code similar to below, but this still needs the `ListIndex=0`.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            .Add ws.Name
        Next ws
        Me.worksheetList.List = .ToArray
    End With

    Me.worksheetList.ListIndex = 0

End Sub
```

**Edit:**  The code assumes the list control is called *worksheetList*.

**Edit 2:**  A slightly different version.  It reverses the items in the list when you click the form.
*It's still Me.worksheetList.ListIndex = 0 to select the item in the list control though*.

```
Option Explicit

Public MyArrayList As Variant

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set MyArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    With MyArrayList
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            .Add ws.Name
        Next ws
        .Sort
        Me.worksheetList.List = .ToArray
    End With

    Me.worksheetList.ListIndex = 0

    ''This will only work in a listbox, not a combobox.
    ''Select items in row numbers that are even (ListIndex 0,2,4, etc)
    ''MultiSelect must be 1 - fmMultiSelectMulti or 2 - fmMultiSelectExtended
    '    Dim x As Long
    '    For x = 0 To Me.worksheetlist.ListCount - 1
    '        If x Mod 2 = 0 Then
    '            Me.worksheetlist.Selected(x) = True
    '        End If
    '    Next x

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

    With MyArrayList
        .Reverse
        Me.worksheetList.List = .ToArray
    End With

    Me.worksheetList.ListIndex = 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether particular element (indicated by index) is selected you should do workaround like this:

```
ComboBox1.Value = ComboBox1.List(i)
```

where `i` is given index. It has to be done like that, because there is no propertry like `SelectedIndex` in VBA `ComboBox`.

Keep in mind, that indexing starts with 0 !

Comment: `Listindex` I think is what you are missing.

Comment: @Rory I don't understand. This code I checked myself and it works :)

Comment: You said "there is no property like SelectedIndex in VBA ComboBox". I'm pointing out that there is.

Comment: I get it now :)